# Reprojecting a Geometry in Hadoop GIS?

Tags: hive, hadoop, spatial-framework-hadoop

I am using [ESRI's spatial framework for Hadoop](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop), in order to add spatial support to Hive.

One scenario that I find very often, is to have layers in different CRS, which I want to relate in the same query. Also, although most things are in WGS84 these days, sometimes it is useful to use a projected CRS, in order to measure things such as areas or distances.

Thus I find that reprojection is a very common need, when working with spatial data. Within PostGIS, I just apply [ST_transform](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) to one geometry, to transform it into another CRS. For instance, this code would reproject the centroid of Barcelona, from whatever crs to an UTM grid:

```
SELECT ST_Transform(ST_Point(2.16991941.387917), 5554);
```

In the [ESRI's function list](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/blob/master/hive/function-ddl.sql), I dont see any mention of ST_Transform. Am I missing something or this no way to achieve this using this framework? Is there any workaround around this?

I believe is a shame if one is not able to perform this operation on a scalable way, since doing it using another tool (for instance PostGIS), could be a bottleneck in a scalable workflow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible at this time.  The geometry library that the Hive ST functions depend on does not support projection.